# Get File Between Two Create Date Time

Tags: c#, file, datetime

My apologies if this question has already been asked but I'm new in programming with C# and I am struggling to solve a date problem I am having. I have written a program that finds a file that has been created between two different date times which I had selected, and check attributes {select} file: that write it but cannot think of for date time :(

```
private bool Check_Attributes(FileInfo finfo)
{
    //check Attributes
    FileAttributes Fattributes = new FileAttributes();
    Fattributes = finfo.Attributes;

    SearchSetAttrib = new List<FileAttributes>();

    if (chkattributes.Checked == true)
    {
        SearchSetAttrib.Clear();
        if (chkreadonly.Checked == true)
            SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

        if (chksystem.Checked == true)
            SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.System);

        if (chkhidden.Checked == true)
            SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Hidden);

        if (chkNormal.Checked == true)
            SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Normal);

        if (chkArchiv.Checked == true)
            SearchSetAttrib.Add(FileAttributes.Archive);

        foreach (FileAttributes FileAtt in SearchSetAttrib)
        {
            if ((Fattributes & (FileAtt)) != 0)
                ReAttrib = true;
            else
                return ReAttrib = false;
        }
    }
    else
        ReAttrib = true;
        return ReAttrib;
}
```

Comment: ... and how is the code snippet related at all?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the creation datetime of a file ? 
This is how to do it:

`DateTime creationDateTime = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\file.txt")`;

**EDIT**

Just to add some more info (might be helpful) this is how you'd query files in a directory based on the creation datetime:

```
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\dir");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles()
                                         .Where(x => x.CreationTime < DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: Wow! I will get File that has it's create time between for EXp: " 08/10/2013 " and "08/02/2012"

Comment: Sure then you would do something like: `.Where(x => x.CreationTime > startDate && x.CreationTime < endDate);`

Comment: thanx this code work good

Comment: Feel free to accept it as an answer if it's what you're looking for :)

Comment: what i do if i will tell that if drive is  d:\ or E:\ or  anything like it do samting

Comment: " if (dirs=="?:\") { //................// }

Comment: You need to do the same for each directory that you need.